# getting error during project creation using phonegap-2.5.0

Tags: android, iphone, linux, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

i have installed android sdk and downloaded the latest version of phonegap 2.5.0 in fedora 18.

i am trying to create a project using the following command

```
./create ~/Desktop/android-project com.example.android android_project
```

am getting the following error.

```
 which: no android in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
    An unexpected error occurred: ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}" exited with 1
```

need your valuable suggestions.

finally found the answer

After checking my .bash_profile paths, and a bunch of digging, I finally found the cause of the issue. If you open up the create file (phonegap-2.5.0/lib/android/bin/create), there is a line that lists ANDROID_BIN=”${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}”. The “which android” is the cause of the issue (or at least it seemed to be in my case). If you replace this line with the full path to your android tools (as listed below) it should resolve the issue. My final line looked like this:

```
ANDROID_BIN=/Users/ktyacke/DEV/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools/android
```

Answer (score 0):

The message you have means the phonegap script cannot find the *android* binary, which is included in the SDK you downloaded.  Add the binary's directory, as well as the android tool's directory, to your path defined in ~/.bash_profile or any other location you're initializing the shell's environment variables.

Comment: Thanks Nate. is it for fedora too?

Comment: i added the follwing lines to bash_profile. But no use of it... PATH=$PATH:/home/yokks/Documents/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:/home/yokks/Documents/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/tools

Comment: @yokks, ```source bash_profile``` or close & reopen the shell and type __which android__.  You should have the path of where the android binary's located returned.

Comment: hi nate, i found the answer. updated the same in the question itself.

Comment: @yokks, see that.  The change you made works, but isn't very optimal.  It's better to have these directories in your path because other phonegap scripts expect these binaries to be there as well.  What happens when you open a new shell and type "which android"?  If a path's returned, then the create script will be able to find the binary too.